# ORACLE date format with +00:00 part

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to execute this oracle delete statement

```
DELETE FROM mySchema.mytable
WHERE myCol= 'abc'
  and DATE_TIME_UTC >= to_date('2011-07-30 00:00:00+00:00','yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS+TZH:TZM')
  and DATE_TIME_UTC <= to_date('2011-07-31 23:55:00+00:00','yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS+TZH:TZM')
```

but I get

> ORA-01821: date format not recognized.

Most likely because of the `+TZH:TZM` part, but I could find any thing on google to get the right format.

I would appreciate your help in setting the right format or pointer to where I can find the right format

Thank you

Comment: In Oracle dates do not have time zones, unlike timestamps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DATE` data type does not contain any time zone information. Use `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` instead, i.e. `to_timestamp_tz('2011-07-30 00:00:00+00:00','yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS+TZH:TZM')`

```
DELETE FROM mySchema.mytable
WHERE myCol= 'abc'
  and DATE_TIME_UTC >= to_timestamp_tz('2011-07-30 00:00:00+00:00','yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS+TZH:TZM')
  and DATE_TIME_UTC <= to_timestamp_tz('2011-07-31 23:55:00+00:00','yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS+TZH:TZM')
```

However, I assume `DATE_TIME_UTC` is a `DATE` value rather than `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`. In this case you must convert your timestamp value into UTC like this:

```
DELETE FROM mySchema.mytable
WHERE myCol= 'abc'
  and DATE_TIME_UTC >= SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(to_timestamp_tz('2011-07-30 00:00:00+00:00','yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS+TZH:TZM'))
  and DATE_TIME_UTC <= SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(to_timestamp_tz('2011-07-31 23:55:00+00:00','yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS+TZH:TZM'))
```

or you can do it the other way around (most likely with less performance):

```
DELETE FROM mySchema.mytable
WHERE myCol= 'abc'
  and FROM_TZ(DATE_TIME_UTC, 'UTC') >= to_timestamp_tz('2011-07-30 00:00:00+00:00','yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS+TZH:TZM')
  and FROM_TZ(DATE_TIME_UTC, 'UTC') <= to_timestamp_tz('2011-07-31 23:55:00+00:00','yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS+TZH:TZM')
```

Of course, since **all** your times are given in UTC you can simplify it and you don't need to consider time zone information at all:

```
DELETE FROM mySchema.mytable
WHERE myCol= 'abc'
  and DATE_TIME_UTC >= to_date('2011-07-30 00:00:00','yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS')
  and DATE_TIME_UTC <= to_date('2011-07-31 23:55:00','yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS')
```

But the solutions above are more generic.

Comment: Thank you.  This is what I am looking for.